# Survey Poll ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, ajax, silverlight

I have a one admin to many clients scenario.

The admin asks questions and the clients are expected to respond with a Yes/No. The communication happens real-time and time to live for one question is say about 2 minutes. So, after 2 minutes, the admin refreshes the question and new question is put up.

I am working with ASP.NET. Before getting started on code, I was wondering if there are any components available that can be used to work with something like this?

I would also be glad if I could get some leads in to developing it otherwise.

Thank You

Comment: could you explain, why you've got that time-requirement ... please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need one scheduler which can put up the question at every 2 min for that you can use Timer class will help you to achieve this easily.

check the example of timer and get detail info at below link of msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like a usual scenario. Building a custom solution won't be that hard. You can have client side js timer or meta refresh tag to keep page refreshed.